# I forgot to set the version of "deployment target". Can I have problems with the app approval?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I forgot to set the version of "deployment target".

My iPhone APP runs only on iOS 5 later, and the deployment target was set to iOS 4.

Can I have problems with the app approval?

Is it better if I submit another version of the app? I can not wait for the return from Apple, because it is an app for a client that has launch deadlines.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a tight deadline, I would reject the app, change the deployment target to 5.0, and resubmit.  If you wait and you do get rejected, then the process will only take longer.

It is fair to say that Apple will try to test the device on iOS 4.  What did you put for Base SDK?

Comment: Base SDK was sent with "Latest iOS 5.1"

Comment: Ok then you only need to change the deployment target, build, and submit.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of XCode (4.4.1), if the deployment target is left empty, it will use the most recent iOS version available in XCode (in my case 6.0).

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question. Then I agree with James, simply resubmit.